# Query number of rows that don't appear in date range of another table

Tags: sql

Imagine I have a table of customers that have unsubscribed from something:

```
DateMonthID     customerID
   201301           123
   201301           321
   201302           987
   201303           567
   201303           728
```

etc etc

and another table of customers that are subscribers each month and their subscription

```
DateMonthID     customerID     subscriptionType
   ...              ...               1
   ...              ...               3
   ...              ...               2
   ...              ...               3
```

etc etc

I need to do a count of all the rows in the first table that don't appear in the second table for 3 months. For example, I need to count customer 987 if he does not appear in the second table between the months of 201302(feb) and 201305(may)

I currently have the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS Total,
    table1.DateMonthID AS MonthID
FROM
    table1
WHERE
table1.DateMonthID <= 201212-3
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2
                        WHERE (table2.DateMonthID >= table1.DateMonthID AND table2.DateMonthID <= (table1.month_key + 3))
                        AND table2.customerID = table1.customerID)
GROUP BY
table1.DateMonthID
```

This gives me outputs that look like

```
Total  MonthID
1000    201301
2345    201302
4532    201303
986     201304
etc      etc
```

This seems fine but what I want to do now is also group by the subscriptiontype. I'm sure this means I need to do a join but being quite new to SQL I'm clueless as to what join and where. I tried doing and inner join between customerIds but ended up having totals that exceeded the amount of record in table one for the corresponding months.

Answer (score 0):

This query, (or using count(*))

```
SELECT
  COUNT(table1.DateMonthID) AS Total,
  subscribers.subscriptionType
FROM
  table1
  INNER JOIN subscribers
     ON table1.DateMonthID = subscribers.DateMonthID
        AND table1.customerID = subscribers.customerID
WHERE
      table1.DateMonthID <= 201212-3
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2
                  WHERE (table2.DateMonthID >= table1.DateMonthID
                    AND table2.DateMonthID <= (table1.month_key + 3))
                    AND table2.customerID = table1.customerID)
GROUP BY subscribers.subscriptionType
```

will give you total number of records by subscriber.

If you want the break out by subscriber and month, add the DateMonthID in the Group.

```
GROUP BY subscribers.subscriptionType, table1.DateMonthID
```

Remember to add table1.DateMonthID to the select to see it on the result.

Comment: I'm not able to test this out until Monday but it does look good. Although wouldn't I want to be grouping by table 1 attributes?

Comment: You're right, I forgot you wanted to group by type not by subscription key.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution but as with Alexanders solution I am getting no results and am not sure where this join to a table called subscribers is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, table1.DateMonthID AS MonthID, subscribers.subscriptionType
FROM table1 JOIN subscribers ON table1.DateMonthID = subscribers.DateMonthID
                                  AND table1.customerID = subscribers.customerID
WHERE table1.DateMonthID <= 201212 - 3
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM table2
                WHERE (table2.DateMonthID >= table1.DateMonthID 
                  AND table2.DateMonthID <= (table1.month_key + 3))
                  AND table2.customerID = table1.customerID)
GROUP BY table1.DateMonthID, subscribers.subscriptionType
```

Comment: This looks great and I've got a good feeling about it. I'll check it out first thing Monday and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi again, I've tried your solution but am getting 0 results back. I've also noticed your joining to a table called subscribers, is this supposed to be table2?